# Return status of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Знаю, что в MSSQL при завершении хранимой процедуры, по дефолту возвращается int значение(статус работы процедуры). Хотел узнать если какой-нибудь список или может справочник в котором написано какой номер какой смысл несёт, однако везде где я смотрел просто сказано, что 0 - процедура проработала успешно, а любой другой номер - ошибка. Мне бы хотелось конкретики.

Answer (score 2):

[Это несложно:](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16#return-data-using-a-return-code)

"Процедура может возвращать целочисленное значение, называемое кодом возврата, чтобы указать состояние выполнения процедуры. Код возврата для процедуры указывается при помощи инструкции RETURN. Как и выходные параметры, при выполнении процедуры код возврата необходимо сохранить в переменной, чтобы использовать это значение в вызывающей программе."

В общем, своими словами: процедура может вернуть любое целое число. Как его интерпретировать - это вопрос *проектирования взаимодействия*.

Обратите внимание, что во первых, число - это лишь один из способов возврата чего нибудь из хранимой (по опыту, они гораздо чаще возвращают результаты `SELECT`-ов), а во вторых, чтобы вернуть "признак ошибки" - есть уже гораздо боле "продвинутые" методы (`TRY/CATCH/THROW`)

Comment: Возможно вы не поняли мой вопрос. Я хочу узнать какой код возврата, что означает(в виде какого либо списка или справочника), а не то что это такое и как это использовать.

Comment: Не хочу ставить на Вашем желании жирный крест, но, мне кажется, такого списка не существует. У идеологогии "ноль-хорошо, не ноль-ошибка" ноги растут из C, в котором bool-а нет, а истина-ложь вполне соответсвует нулевому и не-нулевому int'у. Есть традиция возврата "ошибки отдельно" в гораздо более современном языке GO. Но вот прямо чтобы с кодами... в каждом случае - код свой, погуглите, например, "коды ошибок WinApi"

Comment: Это просто отголоски С(на котором написана СУБД). Списка нет, но вы можете определить его сами: 0 - хорошо; 1 - фатальная ошибка; 2 - таймаут; 3 - деление на 0; 4 - всё остальное и т.д. Тут всё ограничено вашей фантазией. Можно вообще не использовать.

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin - круто, Ваш комментарий - самый ценный во всем обсуждении!